# CSS text-decoration:underline for <details><summary> not works in Safari

Tags: safari, html-tag-details

Why CSS property `text-decoration:underline;` for `<details><summary>` not works in Safari?

Prefixed `-webkit-text-decoration:underline;` doesn’t help either.

It works in all other (include old) browsers. It works in Safari with other selectors. How make it work?

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed as communicated here for Safari newer versions: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261571